# Odd driver update

Tags: drivers, updates

I have this optional driver update in my settings that seems out of place, and I'm not sure whether I should download it or not.

[image]

Comment: I bet you are concerned about the date. The time stamp 1/1/1970, 0:00 is linux epoch for 0 seconds. This basically means that somehow that file has no date entered in the database field on the Microsoft Servers. The version number tells you that it is a correct driver though. Likely a chipset driver for Intel based motherboards.

Answer (score 2):

That driver is an Intel QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller.

It is not on every machine. It is installed on my ThinkPad X230 and not installed on my ThinkPad X1 (not needed).

If it is on your machine, you can very safely let Windows Update do the update from its source. No issue from doing that.

Here are the relevant Screen Shots.

First Windows Update History

[image]

Second Device Driver screen from the X230

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would manually install the driver from the Intel website. I believe this link will help

https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000023446/software/chipset-software.html

or

Install the application on https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ and let the tool perform a system scan.